# Random variables stable by nonlinear function

Tags: distributions, references, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $h$ a function and $X$ a random variable with CDF $F$.

We say that $X$ is stable by $h$ if $h(X)$ follows $F$.

**I would like to know if there is a literature for those kind of random variables?** (Note: [Stable distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) are not closely related).

For example, existence and unicity under some conditions.

*Examples:*
Here are three examples ($h_3$ is adapted from formula to sample Laplace distribution). Let:

$h_1 = \log |x|$

$h_2 = \text{sign}(x) \log |x|$

$h_3 = - \text{sign}(x) \log |1-2x|$

[image: Density stable by h1]
*Density of a random variable stable by $h_1$*

[image: Density stable by h2]
*Density of a random variable stable by $h_2$*

[image: Density stable by h3]
*Density of a random variable stable by $h_3$*

*Code:* Code in R.

```
h1 = function(x) {
  log(abs(x))
}

h2 = function(x) {
  sign(x)*log(abs(x))
}

h3 = function(x) {
  -sign(x)*log(abs(1-2*x))
}

N = 1000000
x = runif(N, -10, 10)
# x = rnorm(N, -8, 9)
for(i in 1:200) {
  print(i)
  x = h3(x)
  if(i %% 50 == 0) {
    hist(x, breaks = 500, main = i, probability = TRUE, xlim = c(-10,10))
  }
}
```

*Note:* I posted a related question in math.stackexchange first, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2701525/solving-fx-fex-f-ex

Comment: I fail to see how your examples illustrate your definition of "stable".  In your third example you have $x \sim U(-10,10)$, and obviously $h(X)$ is not, so by your definition $X$ is not stable by $h$.  Neither of your other two examples work either, AFAICT.

Comment: $x_0$ following $U(-10, 10)$ is the initial step, then we define $x_i = h(x_{i-1})$ and we hope for convergence to $x_{+\infty}$ stable by $h$. In presented examples, no matter initial distribution is uniform or normal, the resulting stable sample seems similar

Comment: Oh, the limiting distribution of a sequence of distributions $F_n$ generated by $x_{n+1} = h(x_n)$.  That clarifies it, thanks.

Comment: You might find something useful in the Wikipedia pages for random dynamical system and measure-preserving dynamical system.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for **random dynamical system** and **measure-preserving dynamical system** (from Dezmond Goff comment).

An accessible introduction can be found in the book *Computational Ergodic Theory*. A chapter of the book is available here: http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540231219 then click on "Download Sample pages 1 PDF (1.6 MB)".

In this chapter book:

- Fig. 2.2 is related with $h = 4 x(1-x)$,
- Fig. 2.5 is related with $h = 1/x - \left \lfloor{1/x}\right \rfloor$,
- Fig. 2.12 is related with $h = |1/x| - \left \lfloor{|1/x| + 1/2}\right \rfloor$,
- Fig. 2.13 is related with $h = 1/x - \left \lfloor{1/x + 1/2}\right \rfloor$.